# Springboot batch Tasklet Validation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-validator

I'm using spring batch tasklets with opencsv to process some csv files. After reading the files into memory in step 1,  in step 2 I'm looking to perform some validation. I'm not sure what the proper approach would be in setting up the validation. I'm using the following code.

```
public class PrimaryCareValidation  implements Tasklet, StepExecutionListener {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PrimaryCareProcessor.class);

    private List<PrimaryCareDTO> batch;

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        logger.info("PrimaryCare validation initialized.");

        ExecutionContext executionContext = stepExecution
                .getJobExecution()
                .getExecutionContext();
        this.batch = (List<PrimaryCareDTO>) executionContext.get("PrimaryCareDTO");
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        logger.info("PrimaryCare validation ended.");
        return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;    }

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        logger.info("PrimaryCare execute.");

        for (PrimaryCareDTO pcDTO : batch) {
            DataBinder binder = new DataBinder(pcDTO); 

            Set<ConstraintViolation<PrimaryCareDTO>> violations = validator.validate(pcDTO);

            for (ConstraintViolation<PrimaryCareDTO> violation : violations)
            {
                String propertyPath = violation.getPropertyPath().toString();
                String message = violation.getMessage();

                result.addError(new FieldError("employee",propertyPath,

                        "Invalid "+ propertyPath + "(" + message + ")"));
            }

        }

        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;    }
}
```

What is the best way to validate am entire DAO list and add the messages to a message object to later be returned to step 3?

Comment: Is there something preventing you form using a chunk-oriented step rather than a tasklet? I'm asking because validation is a typical use case of an item processor so you can implement your validation in an item processor at the item level (unless your validation logic is cross-items and requires the entire list, but this does not seem the case according to your code). If you can use an item processor, then a possible way would be to use a `ItemProcessListener` and write invalid items somewhere that step3 would read.

Comment: Yes there is cross validation and I believe you may have assisted me with it a couple weeks ago. I'm just new to springboot and want to do things the spring way.

Comment: Use a JobExecutionDecider may be a better solution than a tasklet

Answer (score 0):

I've had very similar case, and used for this [vavr](http://www.vavr.io/) library. 
It contains useful `Validation` object which could hold either successful value - in your case it's DTO, or in case of failure - some message. 
Then there are built-in methods which could help you to Squash them into one single aggregated `Validation`.

Please also mind what @Mahmoud noted in comments. It's better to use reader-writer-processor in this case it will leave smaller memory footprint and could be scalable.
Right now you have a risk of having large file which will not fit in your applications memory.

Same relates to your DTO objects. They will remain in the memory unless tasklet will exit. This is a risk of having `OutOfMemoryException`

Please check this article: https://www.baeldung.com/vavr-validation-api

Comment: I would use chunks, but do to cross validation across multiple files I must use tasklets. I'm aware of potential memory issues, but in my use case there is never more than a few thousand lines in the CSV making memory issues non existent. Does your suggestion still make use of the property validation annotations (@NotNull ect)?